# How to transform this list comprehension to a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

How to transform the following list comprehension to a for-loop statement in Python?

```
p = [[S[x] for x in range(len(S)) if i>>x&1] for i in range(2**len(S))]
```

for example: `S = [0,1]`, it should output `[[], [0], [1], [0,1]]`.

I thought it maybe like the following, but I was wrong:

```
p=[]
for x in range(len(S)):
    for i in range(2**len(S)):
        if i>>x&1:
            p.append([S[x]])
```

Comment: Any advance on *"I was wrong"*? Inputs and outputs, for example? One obvious issue is that the original creates nested lists, which your new version doesn't.

Comment: oh, thanks for your advice and all your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nested list comprehension; the outer list comprehension produces a series of lists, each produced by another list comprehension.

This translates to a nested loop where the inner loop also produces a list, that then is append to `p`:

```
p = []
for i in range(2 ** len(S)):
    inner = []
    for x in range(len(S)):
        if i >> x & 1:
            inner.append(S[x])
    p.append(inner)
```

Demo:

```
>>> S = [0, 1]
>>> p = []
>>> for i in range(2 ** len(S)):
...     inner = []
...     for x in range(len(S)):
...         if i >> x & 1:
...             inner.append(S[x])
...     p.append(inner)
...
>>> p
[[], [0], [1], [0, 1]]
```

The output matches the output of the original list comprehension:

```
>>> [[S[x] for x in range(len(S)) if i>>x&1] for i in range(2**len(S))]
[[], [0], [1], [0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't aware of the nested list before.